# Possible bugs in mobile site

Tags: support, bug, mobile-web

Browsing Stack Exchange from my mobile, I report that:

- The "read this post in our app" banner at the top of the page often fails to be present;
- MathJax is not rendered, neither in comments nor in Qs/As;
- All of this vanishes when looking at questions from the Facebook app through a link, i.e. if I share a question on Facebook and then open the link in the Facebook app then no problem.

Is this just my phone, or is someone else experiencing this? I use the basic "Internet" app to browse the web.

**Update**

Seems the banner is only gone on Maths. At least, meta (this question included) and Italian have it. Perhaps I clicked the X and had it gone. Is there a way to have it back when I want it?

**Update 2**

Seems the banner is only gone on Maths, Chinese and TeX -- not even their metas! -- and not on Japanese e.g.. MathJax is not rendered, neither on Math SX nor on meta Math.

**Update 3**

French, Italian and English (ELU) have the banner on mains and metas. Physics also does, and also renders MathJax. Tried to test SO, but was auto-logged out, and here's the result of trying to log back in:

[image]

But that is [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267419/adding-pics-from-mobile-site). So is there some trigger that triggers the disappearance of the banner and/or the non-rendering of MathJax? if so, where is it and how do I get the banner back / MathJax rendered?

Comment: SX? Do you mean SE - Stack Exchange?

Comment: Or SX as Stack Xchange, @Oded :). I've seen people abbreviate it both ways.

Comment: Huh. I've not seen that. And all abbreviations (such as comment magic links) use se.

Comment: @Oded Mick is from the strange country of TeX, this is how [they speak there](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tex-sx)

Comment: Local dialect, it seems :).

Comment: Wait, that's not mobile UI. That's desktop UI on a mobile device. Try clearing cookies/cache? Not sure what options for that are available in your device OS there.