# Adding pics from mobile site

Tags: discussion, bug, mobile-web

I was recently editing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267343/possible-bugs-in-mobile-site) when I needed to include the picture and found I had to do it from the app since the mobile site had no button for it. Is this intended or is it a bug in the mobile site?

Comment: Not all the features of std. desktop browser based site are available on mobile-web. But, good to have this one.